# RTSP stream to RTMP through Nginx-RTMP ffmpeg stream not working

Tags: nginx, multimedia, rtmp, rtsp

I'm trying to convert a RTSP stream to RTMP through exec_pull inside RTMP application block. there are no errors but the stream doesn't work when I try to access it from VLC network stream.

Gihtub issue: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/1353

Below is my configuration file.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
 worker_connections 768;
 # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}



rtmp {
 exec_options on;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/rtmp_access.log;
 server {
       listen 8089;
       #notify_method get;
       application live {
           live on;
           exec_pull ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.x.x.x:8554/Stream1 -threads 2 -f flv -r 25 -s 1280x720 -an rtmp://localhost:8089/stream;
       }
   }
}
```